# perform a select query with CMIS alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis

i am using CMIS javascript api to pull data from an alfresco repository, 
i'm trying to get document in a specific folder (i have the folder object ) 
but the only query that seems to work is

```
"SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE IN_TREE('" + f_id + "') "
```

but this query search recursively, i want the search to be specific the that folder.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to use `IN_FOLDER`.
Reference: http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.1/pra/1/concepts/cmis-query.html